# Unexpected recursions in safari browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, safari

I've tried to implement long polling chat. My chat works correctly, except one browser - safari.
I get new message by this code (here only part, just for understanding recursion):

```js
    let errorCounter = 0;

    let getChatText = function () {
        let options = {
            //headers and other configuration, which needed for XMLHttpRequest
        };

        let responseHandler = function(responseCode, body) {
            switch (responseCode) {
                //handle response codes
                case 200:
                    errorCounter = 0; //on success response
                // other codes handle here
                default:
                    errorCounter++;
            }

            if (errorCounter >= 30) { // 30 just for testing
                endChatSession(true);
            } else {
                getChatText(); //recursion
            }
        };

        requestCall(options, false, responseHandler);
    };
```

If in some moment I reload the page - it doesn't stop, but tryis to call many times (30 in my case) and `endChatSession` on too many errors. But in other browsers (chrome, firefox etc.) - its immediately stops recursion, and reload the page.

Here is a console output, before safari page reload (preserve log):
[image: console output]

`Question`: How can I stop recursion on page reload in safari, because it is not a reason to `endChatSession`

Comment: Not sure how a reload would not still do the recursion on the other browsers since the `errorCounter` would be reset. But you do not show how `errorCounter` is defined so it is an assumption.

Comment: @epascarello I've updated my question. `errorCounter` set to 0 and `endChatSession` only if 30 errors in one line